# WebClient Downloading Zip Files 404 error on redirect

Tags: .net, vb.net, download, zip, webclient

I have 5 zip files i want to download from a website.

> http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part1_5.zip
>   http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part2_5.zip
>   http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part3_5.zip
>   http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part4_5.zip
>   http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part5_5.zip

However if i use the following code i get a 404 error which i think is a result of the http:// being dropped when i navigate to the page in a browser but not when i use my code.

```
    Try
        Dim reg As String = """.*zip"""
        Dim list As New List(Of String)()
        Dim list2 As New List(Of String)()
        Dim myRegex As New Regex(reg, RegexOptions.None)
        TextBox1.Text = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html").ToLower
        For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(TextBox1.Text) 
            list.Add(myMatch.Value)
        Next
        Dim temp As String
        For Each i In list
            temp = i.Remove(0, 1)
            temp = temp.Remove(temp.Length - 1, 1)
            list2.Add(temp)
        Next
        Dim x As Integer = 1
        For Each i In list2
            Dim address As String = "http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/" + i
            Dim des As String = Application.StartupPath + "\" + x.ToString + ".zip"
            Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient()
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
            client.DownloadFile(address, des)
            x = x + 1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 1 To x Step 1
            Shell(Application.StartupPath + "\7za.exe e " + Application.StartupPath + "\" + x + ".zip")
        Next
        list.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Any Ideas?

*Update: I have included the full code instead of a snippet.

Comment: Could you post up how you initialise the list2 variable please. When I use the code above it works fine for me but I have made an assumption on list2 based on your comment in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably what or how you have the file name data stored.  There are one or two other issues in your code:

```
Private filList As New List(Of String) From {"BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part1_5.zip",
                                         "BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part2_5.zip",
                                         "BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part3_5.zip",
                                         "BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part4_5.zip",
                                         "BasicCompanyData-2015-02-01-part5_5.zip"}
```

Then elsewhere such as a button click:

```
Dim destPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
Dim destFile As String
Dim baseURL As String = "http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/"
Dim thisURL As String

Using wc As New WebClient
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", 
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")

    For Each f As String In filList
        thisURL = baseURL & f
        destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, f)
        wc.DownloadFile(thisURL, destFile)
    Next

End Using
```

1. The USING block assures that the WebClient will be closed, disposed and resources released.
2. In VS, using `Application.StartupPath` will work, but as a deployed app that may likely fail when the app is installed to `Program Files...` because your app will likely not be able to write there.  Use `Environment.GetFolderPath` to get folders  such as `MyDocuments`.
3. This version retains the original filename so that if you are doing other files, they wont overwrite each other (another possible issue when using App `StartupPath`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way i found the links on the page, i was reading the webpage into a textbox and applying .toLower to it so the url was wrong when i extracted it.

Problem Line:

```
TextBox1.Text = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html").ToLower
```